# Android error log

Tags: android

I use android LogCat, write logs and it doesn't work. And if i try to debug app it crashes. App works fine. No errors of malfunction, but I need logcat to print logs. Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

I'm using eclipse clasic, updated android SDK and plugin in eclipse (don't remember full name)

Comment: `write logs and it don't work`. What do you mean? No log shown in LogCat?

Comment: "it don't work" is a bit vague.

Comment: Yes, log is like Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE"); but LogCat is empty. It works only when app brokes down

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: It's a huge app that gets info from webserver if it gets info it should log Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE"); and go to next intent (it goes, but no log). If it goes wrong it logs Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE"); and gives a toast with error. LogCat is empty anyway

Answer (score 0):

Restarting eclipse or stoping adb.exe process from task manager will fix this issue.It happens some times.Hope it will help.

Comment: No, sadly it didn't help at all.

Comment: have you selected the device from DDMS.?